# JavaScript to standard Java conversion issue

Tags: java, javascript

I have a JavaScript Method and I need to convert this in standard Java, however I have a little problem with the lines

```
if (jsum) sum += bj;
jsum=!jsum;
```

and

```
return x < 0.0 && (n & 1) ? -ans : ans;
```

That shows the error: *the operator is undefined*.
I know that I can't use this syntax in Java, but I haven't understood what is the right syntax to use to maintain the original purpose without issues

the full JS method is

```
function bessel_fkb(n,x)
{ 
    if (n == null || n.length == 0) return "n not specified";
    var iac = 40.0;     
    var bigno = 1.0e10;
    var bigni = 1.0e-10;
    var j,jsum,m,ax,bj,bjm,bjp,sum,tox,ans;
    ax=Math.abs(x);
    if (ax == 0.0) return 0.0;
    else if (ax > n) {
        tox = 2.0/ax;
        bjm=BesselJ0(ax);
        bj=BesselJ1(ax);
        for (j=1;j<n;j++) {
            bjp=j*tox*bj-bjm;
            bjm=bj;
            bj=bjp;
        }
        ans=bj;
    } else {
        tox=2.0/ax;
        if (Math.sqrt(iac*n) >= 0)
            m=2*((n + Math.floor(Math.sqrt(iac*n))) / 2);
        else
            m=2*((n + Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(iac*n))) / 2);
        jsum=0;
        bjp=ans=sum=0.0;
        bj=1.0;
        for (j=m;j>0;j--) {
            bjm=j*tox*bj-bjp;
            bjp=bj;
            bj=bjm;
            if (Math.abs(bj) > bigno) {
                bj *= bigni;
                bjp *= bigni;
                ans *= bigni;
                sum *= bigni;
            }
            if (jsum) sum += bj;
            jsum=!jsum;
            if (j == n) ans=bjp;
        }
        sum=2.0*sum-bj;
        ans /= sum;
    }
    return x < 0.0 && (n & 1) ? -ans : ans;     
}
```

My Full Java conversion attempt is:

```
public double bessel_fkb(double n, double x)
    { 
        double iac = 40.0;      
        double bigno = 1.0e10;
        double bigni = 1.0e-10;
        double jsum,m,ax,bj,bjm,bjp,sum,tox,ans;
        ax=Math.abs(x);
        if (ax == 0.0) return 0.0;
        else if (ax > n) {
            tox = 2.0/ax;
            bjm=BesselJ0(ax);
            bj=BesselJ1(ax);
            for (int j=1;j<n;j++) {
                bjp=j*tox*bj-bjm;
                bjm=bj;
                bj=bjp;
            }
            ans=bj;
        } else {
            tox=2.0/ax;
            if (Math.sqrt(iac*n) >= 0)
                m=2*((n + Math.floor(Math.sqrt(iac*n))) / 2);
            else
                m=2*((n + Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(iac*n))) / 2);
            jsum=0;
            bjp=ans=sum=0.0;
            bj=1.0;
            for (int j=(int)m;j>0;j--) {
                bjm=j*tox*bj-bjp;
                bjp=bj;
                bj=bjm;
                if (Math.abs(bj) > bigno) {
                    bj *= bigni;
                    bjp *= bigni;
                    ans *= bigni;
                    sum *= bigni;
                }
                if (jsum) sum += bj;
                jsum=!jsum;
                if (j == n) ans=bjp;
            }
            sum=2.0*sum-bj;
            ans /= sum;
        }
        return x < 0.0 && (n & 1) ? -ans : ans;     
    }
```

Comment: Both of those examples are valid syntax.

Comment: @greedybuddha valid *syntax* but not semantically valid

Comment: @greedybuddha
the second method in Java doesn't works due to error in the reported lines

Comment: @Pointy: how is `if (double)` valid in Java??

Comment: @jlordo it's not, but that's a semantic issue and not a syntax issue. (Splitting hairs.)

Comment: SO is not a code porting service. You should ask about how to achieve what the line you mention is supposed to achieve, using a more contained code sample. (I.e. one that shows what the heck `x`, `n`, and `ans` are.)

Comment: @millimoose I haven't ask for porting code service, I want to understand what is the error in my conversion and understand how I could fix the problem, I have added also the full methods to clarify better the variables (in JS there is var, not double, int etc.)

Comment: @AndreaF JS very much has strongly typed objects though. You're expecting someone to wade through 25 lines of code to figure out what the values of those variables are. It's preferrable you "do the legwork" and poke at the JS debugger to find out the actual values when the code is run so that you can only post the least amount of relevant information possible. For the Java error, *which* operator is undefined would've also helped - the line you quote uses 4 different ones.

Comment: Nobody's pointed out yet that Java and JavaScript are really not related in any significant way, so I have now done so. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write this:

```
return x < 0.0 && (n & 1) ? -ans : ans;
```

because `(n&1)` is not a valid operation in Java since *n* is a double, in JavaScript in this way you test whether `n` is *odd* or not, so you have just to write:

```
if(x<0.0 && (int)n%2!=0){
   return -ans;
}
else{
   return ans;
}
```

EDIT:

You have misunderstood the `jsum` role, you cannot see `var jsum` as `double`, in Java must be a `boolean`.

Look at

```
 if (jsum) sum += bj;
            jsum=!jsum;
```

make no sense `jsum` as *double*.

Comment: `(n&1)  is not a valid operation in Java` Wrong. There is bit wise AND in Java.

Comment: Note that if `n` is `double` type, and you use `n % 2`, it will return the floating point remainder, which is total different behaviour compared to how `%` works in JavaScript when it is used with floating point (convert to integer, then find mod).

Comment: @nhahtdh
First of all you CANNOT do bit wise AND with a double in Java, so (n&1) where n is a double isn't a valid operation. Second n%2!=0 verify that the number is odd or not, if the number has a non-null decimal part clearly result is always odd, but this is not important since a not-odd number MUST BE a multiple of 2 without any decimal part and double can have also decimal part 0 according the calculated value in the algorithm and what exactly should do the method isn't specified in the question.

Comment: `First of all you CANNOT do bit wise AND with a double in Java, so (n&1) where n is a double isn't a valid operation.` Of course. `n&1` when n is double is not valid. However `n&1` in **JavaScript** (the original code) will cause implicit conversion from floating point to integer type, then the bit-wise AND will happen. This is equivalent to casting the number to integral type, then perform AND operation in **Java**. If you don't do the integer conversion, then your method is does not closely replicate the effect of **JavaScript** code.

Comment: Let us assume `n` is double type (although the **JavaScript** code seems to imply that `j` and `n` are integral type). Let n = 4.1 in **JavaScript**. `n&1` in JavaScript will cause implicit conversion to integer (4), then `&1` happens and we get 0. With your method in **Java**, `n%2` will produce `0.1`, which is incorrect, since the **expected result from JavaScript is 0**

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (jsum) sum += bj;
```

should be:

```
if (jsum > 0) sum += bj; // or != 0
```

You have to introduce an explicit comparison.

And this:

```
    return x < 0.0 && (n & 1) ? -ans : ans;
```

should be:

```
    return x < 0.0 && ((long) (n & 1) == 1) ? -ans : ans;
```

JavaScript performs implicit conversions from non-boolean types in appropriate contexts, but Java does not. (*edit* ah, oops, have to convert to `long` or something first)

The conversion from `double` to `long` is of course not necessarily meaningful. If the JavaScript code works, then it should be OK.  Of course you could re-do it and make "n" be an integer (or long) if that would work.

Comment: doesn't works, error in (n & 1 == 1)

Comment: @AndreaF That's because `&` isn't defined for `double` in Java. In JavaScript binary operators like `&` will cause both operands to be converted to integers. Pointy, shouldn't `if (jsum)` be translated to `if (jsum != 0)` anyway?

Comment: @AndreaF ok updated.  I don't know about "jsum"; I guessed `>` but you're right, perhaps `!= 0` is better.

Comment: @NullUserException
Thanks, any suggestion to explicit the return line, avoiding to use &?

Comment: @AndreaF: Most likely `(n&1)` is testing whether `n` is odd or not.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `n` is likely to be `int` type instead of `double`, and `jsum` is most likely to be `int` or `boolean` type.

The answer below assume `n` to be `int` type and `jsum` to be `boolean` type.

In JavaScript:

```
jsum = 0;
...
if (jsum) sum += bj;
jsum = !jsum;
```

In Java:

```
jsum = false;
...
if (jsum) sum += bj;
jsum = !jsum;
```

In JavaScript:

```
return x < 0.0 && (n & 1) ? -ans : ans;
```

In Java:

```
return x < 0.0 && (n & 1) != 0 ? -ans : ans;
```

If `n` actually expects type `double`, then you must case `n` to `long` before doing bit-wise AND `&` with 1.

Since Java has strict typing, it may be good to figure out the actual usage and use the type accordingly.

Comment: shows error in (n & 1)

Comment: @AndreaF: Edited. But I don't know what your function does, so the guess might be off.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments should be int, and jsum sum as i see is used like a boolean

try that:

```
public double bessel_fkb(int n, double x)
{ 
    double iac = 40.0;      
    double bigno = 1.0e10;
    double bigni = 1.0e-10;
    double m,ax,bj,bjm,bjp,sum,tox,ans;
    boolean jsum;
    ax=Math.abs(x);
    if (ax == 0.0) return 0.0;
    else if (ax > n) {
        tox = 2.0/ax;
        bjm=BesselJ0(ax);
        bj=BesselJ1(ax);
        for (int j=1;j<n;j++) {
            bjp=j*tox*bj-bjm;
            bjm=bj;
            bj=bjp;
        }
        ans=bj;
    } else {
        tox=2.0/ax;
        if (Math.sqrt(iac*n) >= 0)
            m=2*((n + Math.floor(Math.sqrt(iac*n))) / 2);
        else
            m=2*((n + Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(iac*n))) / 2);
        jsum=false;
        bjp=ans=sum=0.0;
        bj=1.0;
        for (int j=(int)m;j>0;j--) {
            bjm=j*tox*bj-bjp;
            bjp=bj;
            bj=bjm;
            if (Math.abs(bj) > bigno) {
                bj *= bigni;
                bjp *= bigni;
                ans *= bigni;
                sum *= bigni;
            }
            if (jsum) sum += bj;
            jsum=!jsum;
            if (j == n) ans=bjp;
        }
        sum=2.0*sum-bj;
        ans /= sum;
    }
    return x < 0.0 && ((n & 1) != 0) ? -ans : ans;     
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but same problem of the others answer in (n & 1) in the last line

Comment: @AndreaF `public double bessel_fkb(int n, double x)` n and x is now an int

Comment: I don't see why `x` must be `int`. `n` seems to be `int`, but there is no reason for `x` to be `int`.

Comment: @nhahtdh yeah you have reason, EDITED